# Copy an entire Model's database and insert into same table with columns changed

Tags: php, laravel

OK. let's say I have a model called `Questions` which is handled by admins. Each of those questions had a column called `master` set to `true`.

How can I make it, so that I can duplicate all of that entire database table and copy it into the same table with the columns `master` set to `false` and `user_id` set to something else.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this instead of doing it the old fashioned way.

Comment: Maybe: $questions=Questions:all(). Foreach($questions as $question) { $question->master= false; OtherTable::insert($question->toArray());}

Comment: do you want to update entire data? Or you want to copy entire data and insert again with master=false?

Comment: @Sohel0415 The 2nd one.

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this solution and it works perfectly. Based on your comments:

```
$questions = Questions::all();
$questions = $questions->map(function($i) use($userId) {
    $i = array_except($i, 'id'); // Remove IDs to make insert() work
    $i->master = false;
    $i->user_id = $userId;
    return $i;
})->toArray();
Questions::insert($questions);
```

It will create just one query to get all the data and one query to insert all modified data.

Comment: I want to carbon-copy every single data row where `master` = `true` paste that on the same table. So if I have 20 rows of data with `master` set to `true`. Copy/paste and now I have 40 rows with the last 20 `master` set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab all record that have master=true first like-

```
$questions = Questions:where('master',true)->get();
```

Or all previous record like

```
$questions = Questions:all();
```

After that insert again like-

```
 foreach ( $questions as $question ) { 
    $question->master=false;
    $question->user_id=$your_other_user_id;
    $q = new Questions();
    $q=$question->replicate();
    $q->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$questions = Questions:all();

foreach ( $questions as $question ) { 
    $question->master = false;
    $q = new Questions(); // Model should be singular
    // copy fields here (maybe it can be done faster, but it works)
    $q->master = $question->master;
    $q->save();
}
```

I know this loop is not very efficient, but it looks like you only will be doing this 1 time.

Comment: What about the questions that were copied? I don't want copy the questions that were already copied.... right?

Comment: Well you select on line 1, so it will only copy the ones from that very moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

    `$questions=Questions::all();
    Foreach($questions as $question)
    $q=$question-replicate();
    $q->master=false;
    $q->save()`